# Stripping / appending characters from user password before hashing to conceal it forever?

Tags: cryptography, passwords, hash, brute-force, cryptanalysis

I had this idea to permanently conceal user password by requiring minimum length then stripping certain characters. For example if the user password is `secret123`, the system will strip it down to `ecrt12`, add random characters to it like `ecrt12!@#$%^&*` before hashing, adding salt, etc, then storing to DB.

Granting all common practices were also used like:

- unique salt per user
- system pepper
- bcrypt/scrypt or whatever latest best crypto algo available

To summarize in code:

`$hash = hash($modifiedpassword.$uniquesalt.$systempepper)` // iterated to 1000s.

In the event an attacker manages to reverse all hashes, the best info they could ever recover is `ecrt12!@#$%^&*` and not the original `secret123`. Even if they hack the system code, they will never know what characters were stripped.

My question now is as security experts, would you recommend this practice of stripping/appending the original user password?

Comment: I don't see how this method could possibly work. What do you do with the result of all this hashing? What use could it possibly be? If you want to conceal it forever and don't mind writing it in a form that's not usable, why write it to the database at all?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The hashes are usable. I am not sure if I get your question but if you are asking how to authenticate on login (since passwords have been stripped), the system just repeats the process on login. It strips predefined character positions from the password and appends the previously added salt.

Comment: How can it re-add the same random characters?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz those will be stored in DB as user-specific salt

Comment: Your question says the random characters are added *before* the salt is added: "*add random characters to it* like ecrt12!@#$%^&* *before* hashing, *adding salt*, etc,"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz There effectively 3 salts total. One of which is with `$modifiedpassword` this is where random characters are added. The other two "salts" are `$uniquesalt` and `$systempepper`

Comment: The three salts do no more than one salt. This is complexity for the sake of complexity.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The number salt is not the point of this question but modification of original password before hashing. I just added salt to mix like mentioned: "granting all common practices were used like salt, etc"... just to prevent other people from saying "you need salt, etc etc."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Kindly enlighten why you don't like complexity where as we all know the more slower, the more complex, the longer an attacker will take to reverse hashes.

Comment: there's no difference between "adding six random characters to the password and adding a salt" and "adding a salt six characters longer than I first thought of". @DavidSchwartz is saying the cases are degenerate.

Answer (score 5):

How would you guarantee that the "same" random characters are used every time the same user enters their password? You can only guarantee that if you write them down (or otherwise deterministically generate them), so "!@#$%^&*" in your "password" is actually just another part of the salt.

This leaves you in a situation where you've converted the user's password from "secret123" to the regular expression "^.ecret12.$", which reduces the password's effective complexity from 9 characters to 7 characters. An attacker who tries "pecret129" will be allowed in.

To answer the question directly and to borrow a quote from ewanm89 below: no. I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: To sum up, no we do not recommend it.

Comment: The hacker's intention is NOT to login to the same system anymore. He already have the whole DB, no need to login to get any other info as he already have everything needs including the password protected info. The important thing here is the original password is still concealed forever. The benefit is, the password `ecrt12!@#$%^&*` or `pecret129` will not work with other systems like Facebook/banking/email.

Comment: @IMB they may not have the _full_ password, but they only have two characters to guess. It's like playing Mastermind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows

Comment: I fully agree that the cost of this is the ability to somehow "regex" the login. But given the system has already been compromised, this implementation does add an extra layer of "slowness" to decrypt which is the goal of password hashing right?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's harder to discover a longer password from a hash than it is to discover a shorter password and then mess around guessing a couple of cleartext characters. Cryptographic hash functions are designed with that in mind.

Comment: not to mention, if I was to do an online attack where I just start cycling through passwords I stick in the box (albeit slowly if there are other protections) it's easier. This doesn't make finding the password from the hash any easier or harder, and it does make a bruteforce attack easier). Ultimately it serves no purpose other than doing more work in the password function, and negligibly at best. Just bcrypt(password.length + password + salt) and be done with it.

Comment: @IMB: Your logic is incorrect. In your example, it's pretty obvious that "secrt12" is "secret12". So he will be able to guess them. And the removed characters means he'll have fewer combinations to guess to find "secrt12". Consider if the password is "foo,bar". That's harder to guess than "foobar". But if you let him do it in two steps by removing the comma before hashing, then it isn't any harder.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz in my example it's not `secrt12` it was `ecrt12` and that is just an "example"... of course the actual password could've been `@#%!@^(!&@&*!` rather than `foo,bar`.

Comment: @IMB in the real world, most people use passwords like "password" and "iloveyou". I'm afraid if your goal is to wait until someone edits the "no" answer and changes it into a "yes", you'll be waiting a very long time.

Comment: @GrahamLee Nope, it fact I agree specially with your point of regex. It's just that I am not sure what else DavidSchwartz is trying to prove (no offense). He argues about arbitrary passwords `it's pretty obvious that "secrt12" is "secret12".`  or `Consider if the password is "foo,bar". That's harder to guess than "foobar"` If anything, that doesn't make any critical argument. Basically he just repeats what you already said.